# WPF. Axis system

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas

How to change axis system in the WPF canvas?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you want to change it to and why.

Comment: Firstly, I want to shift zero point (0,0) from the upper left corner into center of my canvas (ActualWidth/2, ActualHeight/2)
Secondly, I want to rotate my axis system at 180 without turning the child elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/) shows how you can do this with a render transform in his great book [Applications = Code + Markup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619573).

On page 844 and following, there is a nice little sample application that he has titled Canvas Modes that illustrates how to do it. But basically, you will want to use a ScaleTransform and a TranslateTransform.

To make the origin the center of the Canvas with Y values going down:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="ActualWidth/2" Y="ActualHeight/2"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

To make the origin the center of the Canvas but with Y values going up:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="ActualWidth/2" Y="ActualHeight/2"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

Of course, I'm using a little bit of pseudo code here for ActualWidth and ActualHeight ...

Comment: You can bind to ActualWidth and ActualHeight since they are dependency properties ... but you will need to use a value converter to divide by 2. Simple enough to do ... but clutters up the answer. :)